# Android: How to set private MutableLiveData in unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am trying to test my `viewmodel` by writing some unit tests. My problem is that I can't achieve my goals, without setting some values for the MutableLiveData *manually* (in production they are set via databinding). The problem here is that my MutableLiveData is (obviously) `private` and therefore I can't set the value by writing `mutablelivedata.value = "Some Value"` in my unit test.

I've read some articles and some say that I just should expose my MutableLiveData by writing a custom setter like:

```
private val _myMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val myPublicLiveData: LiveData<String> get() = _myMutableLiveData

// setter
fun setStringForLiveData(value: String) {
   _myMutableLiveData.value = value
}
```

Here comes my question: WHAT is the point of setting the MutableLiveData to `private` but exposing the setter with a custom `setStringForLiveData(value: String)` and the getter with `myPublicLiveData`. I mean when I expose both the getter and setter of my `private` field why shouldn't I just make it public?

Here is my current approach to test my MutableLiveData (I don't know if this makes any sense or even works)

```
@Test
fun `first shipping text should be set correctly`() {
   (viewModel.secondDropDownVisibility as MutableLiveData<Boolean>).value = false
   (viewModel.shippingFirstDdText as MutableLiveData<String>).value = "Toast"
    assertEquals("Toast", viewModel.decideShippingTextOne())
}
```

I hope there is a better way than writing a custom setter for every mutablelivedata (I have over 20 and this is just ugly boilerplate code). Maybe I have misunderstood something here.

Please bear in mind that I am rather new to Android Development and the concept of MVVM and especially Livedata.

I appreciate every help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this may not be the best answer, but this works for me. At this point, I don't really care about "oh no, but this is not right in android programming" or "but you shouldn't do that in unit testing". The test cases work and that's all I need.

```
@Test
fun `first shipping text should be set correctly`() {
   (viewModel.secondDropDownVisibility as MutableLiveData<Boolean>).value = false
   (viewModel.shippingFirstDdText as MutableLiveData<String>).value = "Toast"
    assertEquals("Toast", viewModel.decideShippingTextOne())
}
```

I have two private field `_secondDropDownVisibility` and `_shippingFirstDdText` of type `MutableLiveData<T>` and two public fields `secondDropDownVisibility` and `shippingFirstDdText` of type `LiveData<T>`

Cheers

Comment: I am using this but I am confused about why this works and if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Your answer helped me in my issue. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

You should just make the MutableLiveData public as is if you need to modify it from outside (without any additional guarantees made to the methods).

If you had been using Databinding, you'd be exposing ObservableField, which is also read/writeable.

Comment: But I only need to modify the MutableLiveData in my TESTS and nowhere else. I highly doubt that this is the recommended way.. Why would I make something public which is NORMALLY private just to test is? That is hideous. And no, I am not using observableField for my databinding (no one should do that), I am using normal lifecycle-aware lifedata.

Comment: exposing fields just for test purposes its usually a code smell, it means you are not designing with test in mind

Comment: If you can't access it from outside, then don't access it from tests ‍♀️

Answer (score -1):

```
private val _myMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val myPublicLiveData: LiveData<String> get() = _myMutableLiveData

// setter
fun setStringForLiveData(value: String) {
   _myMutableLiveData.value = value
}
```

Sorry but this code just doesn't make sense. If you absolutely need to go this way, then there is no need to go with the double fields as you are exposing the mutable state anyway.

That being say I´d argue that you need resort to this and its usually a code smell. I cant see your whole view model but I´d assume you have a public function ( or some init code ) that triggers some work and it pushes data to the live data, and that's what you have to test instead. If you want to upload your full view model I could try to suggest the testing approach by updating the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I will try to rethink my approach, maybe I don't even need to test these "specific functions inside my viewmodel" because they just use other public functions from my models, which I already tested. I don't think that I can post the whole Viewmodel because it has over 400lines of code (responsible for a navgraph with 3 fragments and a lot of edittext's)